# Group episodes by seasons from db

Tags: php, mysql

I have database, that contains info about tv series like this:

```
name - Californication
episode - 3
season - 6

name - Californication
episode - 4
season - 6
..
name - Californication
episode - 1
season - 7
```

I want to get the output like this:

```
Season 6:
episode 3
episode 4

Season 7:
episode 1
episode 2
....
```

Tried in several ways, and even succeeded, but I believe it is better to ask here for a light method.
thanks

Comment: What succeeded? Where is the query, table names, column names, etc?

Comment: Can you show what you came up with so we can see if we have something better to suggest?

Comment: It was pretty terrible idea that got the count of how many seasons are there and then run several queries in a loop, so I believe anything would be better :D

Comment: Can't you just group by name and season?

Comment: nope that doesnt seem to do what i`m asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do all of the grouping in PHP.

```
$seasons = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    if (!isset($seasons[$row->season]) {
        $seasons[$row->season] = array();
    }
    $seasons[$row->season][] = $row->episode;
}
```

The result is multi-dimensional array with each season as a key with an array of its episodes as the value.

Comment: tried it this way
`$seasons = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($k)) {

 if (!isset($seasons[$row['season']])) {
        $seasons[$row['season']] = array();
    }
    $seasons[$row['season']][] = $row['episode'];

print_r($seasons);`

got some pretty nasty output

`Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
        )

)
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 10
        )

)
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 9
        )

)
`
what did I do wrong?

Comment: @Treat looks fine to me, but don't you want to `print_r` outside of the `while` loop?

Comment: well it is 6AM :D Thanks, that was what I was looking for :)